# C++ Builder 10.4 community edition => scoped_lock are missing (at least seems to be a path mess)

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++17, c++builder

Just installed C++Builder 10.4 Community Edition. My app is a console multi-threaded app, and uses `std::scoped_lock` (C++17).

It seems that C++Builder chooses a `<mutex>` header file that does not define `scoped_lock` in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\include\dinkumware64`, where the `<mutex>` header file that is in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\include\dinkumware64\Dinkum\threads` actually *does* define them, but is not the one used during include resolution.

What am I missing? Has this ever been tested?

Launch C++Builder fresh from install, create a new console, multi-threaded application, take the pre-generated shim code for `main()` and add this code:

```cpp
#pragma hdrstop
#pragma argsused

#include <mutex>

#ifdef _WIN32
#include <tchar.h>
#else
  typedef char _TCHAR;
  #define _tmain main
#endif

#include <stdio.h>

std::mutex m;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) 
{
    std::scoped_lock lock(m);
    return 0;
}
```

And that will fail with an error:

> no member named "std::scoped_lock" in namespace "std"

The application is 32 bits, debug. I've tried 64 bits as the `<mutex>` header is strangely located under `dinkumware64/mutex`, and debug no/debug, I've tried changing various options but no avail.

Now under `dinkumware64/Dinkum/threads/`, there is another "mutex" package that includes `scoped_lock`, but I have no idea why C++Builder selects it or not, and it's not in the `std` namespace anyway.

Comment: Please show a proper [mre] including details on how you are compiling it or how you set up the project.

Comment: Example added (see edit)

Comment: When compiling for 32bit, which compiler are you using, exactly?  The "classic" Borland 32bit compiler is NOT a C++11 compiler.  The "non-classic" 32bit compiler, and the 64bit compiler, are CLang C++17 compilers.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the "non-classic", I even tried to force the support by adding "-std=c++17" on extra command line. The thing is that in the Dinkumware std library, in mutex or in thread includes, "scoped_lock" is not even defined...

Comment: If you look there, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/17, it says since 10.3 scoped_lock is supported, but then, where is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard library is located in `dinkumware64` for 32-bit programs as well, so you should be looking there.

Problem is that `scoped_lock` [is missing](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-25839) from the standard library.

You can easily implement this class by yourself by using [`std::lock`](https://%20https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock), or just use `std::lock_guard` if you only have one mutex.

Comment: Thanks - Yes I know I can use std:lock or std:lock_guard but as it is an existing multi-platform application, I was hopping to just not have to do that to have less spaghetti. Well, it's unfortunate because I've been using C++ Builder for ages, but that will likely be the nudge to push me to VS as the C++17 compliance seems much higher (and I'm not trying *at all* to start a discussion on that topic)